# ROS-i ABB Unable to access some members of industrial_msgs/CmdJointTrajectory

Tags: ros, ros-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am basically trying to subscribe to the rostopic which broadcast the `sensor_msgs/JointState` and then call the `/joint_path_command` service to move the ABB robot in robot studio simulation. Hence, Whenever there is new joint positions in that topic, I will call `/joint_path_command` to mvoe the robot accordingly.

I have managed to receive the joint states from the rostopic. However, I have encountered problem when trying to create `industrial_msgs/CmdJointTrajectory` message which is required for the `/joint_path_command` service.

---

```
void chatterCallback(const sensor_msgs::JointState::ConstPtr &msg)
{
  for(int i = 0; i<msg->position.size(); i++)
  {
    posi.push_back(msg->position.at(i));
  }

  for(int i = 0; i<msg->velocity.size(); i++)
  {
    velo.push_back(msg->velocity.at(i));
  }  

  for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
  {
    acc.push_back(0.0);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i<msg->effort.size(); i++)
  {
    eff.push_back(msg->effort.at(i));
  }
  
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<industrial_msgs::CmdJointTrajectory>("joint_path_command");
  industrial_msgs:CmdJointTrajectory srv;
  srv.request.trajectory.header = msg->header;
  srv.request.trajectory.joint_names = jointnames;
  srv.request.trajectory.points.positions = posi;
  srv.velocities = velo;
  srv.accelerations = acc;
  srv.effort = eff;

  //  srv.request.trajectory.points = srvvv;

  //  srv.time_from_start = ros::Time::now();

  if(client.call(srv))
  {
    ROS_INFO("hoolay");
  }
}
```

above is my program that tries to call the `joint_path_command` service with the information gathered from a `sensor_msg/JointState` msg.

Below is the compilation result

```
[100%] [100%] Built target add_two_ints_client
Built target add_two_ints_server
/home/colin/catkin_ws/src/armpost_listener/src/listen_armpost.cpp: In function 'void chatterCallback(const ConstPtr&)':
/home/colin/catkin_ws/src/armpost_listener/src/listen_armpost.cpp:66:33: error: 'trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory_<std::allocator<void> >::_points_type' has no member named 'positions'
   
srv.request.trajectory.points.positions = posi;

                                 
/home/colin/catkin_ws/src/armpost_listener/src/listen_armpost.cpp:67:33: error: 'trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory_<std::allocator<void> >::_points_type' has no member named 'velocities'

   srv.request.trajectory.points.velocities = velo;
                                 ^

/home/colin/catkin_ws/src/armpost_listener/src/listen_armpost.cpp:68:33: error: 'trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory_<std::allocator<void> >::_points_type' has no member named 'accelerations'

   srv.request.trajectory.points.accelerations = acc;
                                 ^
/home/colin/catkin_ws/src/armpost_listener/src/listen_armpost.cpp:69:33: error: 'trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory_<std::allocator<void> >::_points_type' has no member named 'effort'

   srv.request.trajectory.points.effort = eff;
                                 ^
make[2]: *** [armpost_listener/CMakeFiles/listen_armpost.dir/src/listen_armpost.cpp.o] Error 1

make[1]: *** [armpost_listener/CMakeFiles/listen_armpost.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2

Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

As you can see, The compiler does not recognize the members of the points struct within trajectory/points (positions, velocities, effort, accelerations) of the `industrial_msgs/CmdJointTrajectory` when it is clearly stated in the rossrv show(shown below)

```
colin@Colin-GF:~$ rossrv show industrial_msgs/CmdJointTrajectory
trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory trajectory
  std_msgs/Header header
    uint32 seq
    time stamp
    string frame_id
  string[] joint_names
  trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint[] points
    float64[] positions
    float64[] velocities
    float64[] accelerations
    float64[] effort
    duration time_from_start
---
industrial_msgs/ServiceReturnCode code
  int8 SUCCESS=1
  int8 FAILURE=-1
  int8 val
```

Am I doing something wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249322/ros-i-abb-unable-to-access-some-members-of-industrial_msgs/cmdjointtrajectory/) by [ninanona](https://answers.ros.org/users/28699/ninanona/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-04**:
Just curious: what are you trying to achieve exactly? The code you include above seems to be sending the robot back to where it already is (ie: setpoint == current_state).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`points` in `srv.request.trajectory.points` is an array as you correctly note in your question. Thus, you should access its elements in order to access their members (e.g. positions, velocities and accelerations). Instead of

`srv.request.trajectory.points.positions`

try

`srv.request.trajectory.points[i].positions`

where `i` is the joint you want to specify.

You might also benefit from this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/54962/understanding-trajectory_msgsjointtrajectory/?answer=54966#post-id-54966).

---

Originally posted by [jsanch2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/25919/jsanch2s/) with karma: 136 on 2016-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ninanona](https://answers.ros.org/users/28699/ninanona/) on 2016-12-04**:
Thank you so much! I didn't realise the point array meant the trajectory points. It solved my problem!